# Access Session from EntityRepository

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine

I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine2. I want to achieve the following:

```
 $place = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TETestBundle:Place')->find($id);
```

And on that place will be the info of the place (common data + texts) on the user language (in session). As I am going to do that hundreds of times, I want to pass it behind the scenes, not as a second parameter. So an English user will view the place info in English and a Spanish user in Spanish.

One possibility is to access the locale of the app from an EntityRepository. I know it's done with services and DI but I can't figure it out!

```
// PlaceRepository
class PlaceRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function find($id)
    {
        // get locale somehow
        $locale = $this->get('session')->getLocale();

        // do a query with the locale in session
        return $this->_em->createQuery(...);
    }
}
```

How would you do it? Could you explain with a bit of detail the steps and new classes I have to create & extend? I plan on releasing this Translation Bundle once it's ready :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about why it is you're trying to do this in the first place? In a normal MVC architecture, things like locale would be the responsibility of the Controller and View, not the Model. I'm wondering if there might be a better way of doing what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that Doctrine is a good approach for accessing session data. There's just too much overhead in the ORM to just pull session data.

Check out the [Symfony 2 Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) for configuration of PDO-backed sessions.

Rather than setting up a service, I'd consider an approach that used a [Doctrine event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html). Just before each lookup, the listener would pick out the correct locale from somewhere (session, config, or any other place you like in the future), inject it into the query, and like magic, your model doesn't have to know those details. Keeps your model's scope clean.

You don't want your model or Repository crossing over into the sessions directly. What if you decide in the future that you want a command-line tool with that Repository? With all that session cruft in there, you'll have a mess.

Doctrine event listeners are magically delicious. They take some experimentation, but they wind up being a very configurable, out-of-the-way solution to this kind of query manipulation.

**UPDATE:** It looks like what you'd benefit from most is the [Doctrine Translatable Extension](http://gediminasm.org/article/translatable-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2). It has done all the work for you in terms of registering listeners, providing hooks for how to pass in the appropriate locale (from wherever you're keeping it), and so on. I've used the Gedmo extensions myself (though not this particular one), and have found them all to be of high quality.

Comment: thanks Clay, but I can't find the Doctrine event listener that I should you before the query is executed. I've found persist, flush, but nothing preQuery, preSelect, preLookup...

Comment: @fesja I updated the answer with an additional link. If you find it helpful, please up-vote my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to create an alternative to that Translatable Extension because I don't like how it's done. I want one row per object-language. That extension creates a row per translated field. So if I have 3 languages and 6 fields to translate, I want just 3 rows, not 18. It's not efficient that extension.

Comment: @fesja Ah, I see. Didn't realize that about the extension. Still, the overall approach is still solid -- a Doctrine extension/listener is a good way to address this. Sounds like a different storage model (to wind up with fewer rows) would probably just be a matter of extending/modifying Translatable. I agree fewer rows would likely be better.